# React and tailwind: making tooltip

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to make tooltips for icons in my header, and right now I have made a component to make the icon and tooltip into one div, with tailwind styles in that

JSX Component:

```
const HeaderIcon = ({ icon, redirect = window.location.pathname.replace('/', ""), text = ""}:IconProps) => (
        <div className="group relative flex items-center justify-center h-12 w-12 mt-2 mb-2 mx-5 cursor-pointer">
            <button onClick={() => goto(redirect)} className="items-center inline-flex">{icon}</button>
            <span className="group-hover:visible absolute rounded-md shadow-md text-white bg-gray-900 text-xs font-bold transition-all duration-100 p-2 text-center min-w-max invisible">
                {text}
            </span>
        </div>
    )
```

Here goto is a redirect function, icon is a JSX element from [react-feather](https://www.npmjs.com/package/feather-icons) (icon library), redirect is a string telling the button where to redirect to, and text is the tooltip text. What tailwind classes should I use to position the tooltips under the icons, centered.

If there is any other things you may want then just ask and I will edit the code in.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a new variant `group-hover` for the plugin `visibility` in the Tailwind configuration:

```js
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  variants: {
    extend: {
      visibility: ['group-hover'],
    }
  },
}
```